# Defer Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, deferred, observable

I am using a standard WebSocket which sends messages and eventually receives a response. Previously, I have used `$q.defer`, stored the deferred object and returned a promise. The response handler would look up the stored deferred object and resolve it using a value.

Is this possible using observables?

```
// As part of the websocket setup
websocket.onmessage = function(message) {
    uuid = message.someResponse.uuid;
    this._observables[uuid].create(function(observer) {
        observer.onNext(response);
        observer.onCompleted();
    });
}

public sendRequest(request : any) : Observable<any> {
    this.sendMessage(request);
    return this._observables[request[Object.keys(request)[0]].uuid] = new Observable();
}

// Inside some requesting method
var observable = this.sendRequest(request);
observable.subscribe(
    response => console.log(response),
    response => console.log(response.error),
    () => {
        delete this._callbacks[uuid];
    }
);
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, RxJS already support websockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor your code this way:

```
public initialize() : Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    websocket.onmessage = function(message) {
      uuid = message.someResponse.uuid;
      observer.next(message);
    }
  });
}
```

and the way to send and received messages as well:

```
var observable = initialize();

var request = (...)
this.sendRequest(request);

observable.subscribe(
  message => {
    // called each time a message is received
    console.log(message)
  },
  response => {
    console.log(response.error)
  },
  () => {
  }
);
```

In the contrary to promises, observables needs to be initialize once since they support events. Each time a message is sent, the event callback (the first parameter of the `subscribe` method) will be called with the message as parameter.

For more details you could have a look the following article in section "Event-based support":

- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html